# React Native Navigator HeaderBackButton "Label" prop not working

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

I am attempting to alter the functionality of the `HeaderBackButton` in navigator, and am doing the following inside of `useEffect()`, based on [the documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements/#headerbackbutton).

```js
navigation.setOptions({
    headerLeft: () =>  <HeaderBackButton label="Back" onPress={navigation.popToTop} />
});
```

It is expected that the label for the button be changed to whatever the `label` prop is set to. All that is being changed is the `onPress` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that in `@react-navigation/elements` 1.3.17, even on iOS the `labelVisible` prop is defaulted as false. [Although the documentation states otherwise](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements/#headerbackbutton), you need to set this prop to true inside of your `HeaderBackButton`, regardless of your target OS.